# JDK 17 ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR with Chrome and Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, openjdk-17

When I ran Selenium tests using selenium/standalone-chrome:97.0 I am getting the following error with JDK 17.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I am accessing the web app with a hostname (not localhost). When I tried with JDK 16 with the same configuration I didn't get the error.

Appreciate it if anyone has any insight into this. Was there some SSL change introduced in JDK17 that causes this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of this issue was I was using a hostname with an underscore (_). I suspect due to some changes, hostnames with underscore not supported in JDK17 (This worked fine with JDK16).

```html
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The encoded server name value is invalid
        at javax.net.ssl.SNIHostName.<init>(SNIHostName.java:179) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.ServerNameExtension$CHServerNamesSpec.<init>(ServerNameExtension.java:131) ~[?:?]
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Contains non-LDH ASCII characters
        at java.net.IDN.toASCIIInternal(IDN.java:297) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.IDN.toASCII(IDN.java:123) ~[?:?]
        at javax.net.ssl.SNIHostName.<init>(SNIHostName.java:175) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.ServerNameExtension$CHServerNamesSpec.<init>(ServerNameExtension.java:131) ~[?:?]
        ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional checks if the `SNIHostName` conforms the [RFC 3490](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3490.html) were introduced in Java 17.

See details in:

- https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/4f4d0f5366a8926f373ea25774a536399281c841
- https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8261969